# SUMIFs based on partial string

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs

I am trying to sum column B by searching for the symbols in D2. As you can see, the start of the symbol is the only bit that needs to be matched. (EW4 DEC18, EW DEC18) How do I do this? Also some of these symbols are more than 3 letters at the start, which complicates thing a little too!

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Use wild cards:

```
=SUMIF(A:A,"*" & D2 & "*",B:B)
```